# Why can't I compile this simple thread test?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos

I wanted to test some things with threads on my Macbook pro, but I can't get it to work.

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

this is the Version of clang installed on my machine. I tried to code some vector of threads but that didn't work so I went back and copied an example from SO.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

// The function we want to execute on the new thread.
void task1(string msg)
{
    cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}

int main()
{
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");

    // Do other things...

    // Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
    t1.join();
}
```

But I am getting a compiler error..

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'std::__1::thread'
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");
```

I guess my machine is the problem, but why?

Comment: parameter "Hello" is not a string

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux - Doesn't matter, the decayed pointer can be used to initialize a string

Comment: @HWilmer, do you add an explicit `-std=c++11` (or higher) flag to your compiler invocation?

Comment: Show your build command please. The posted code works with `Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)` on my rig with `clang++ --std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -o main  main.cpp`

Comment: Alright that was the reason! Thank you guys. First time I am actually compiling with command line. I should read up on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow, you built your code as C++03, probably by not providing a standard revision flag explicitly. libc++, the LLVM implementation of the standard library allows using `<thread>` in C++03 code. The source has conditional compilation of the [following sort](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/90e87af303acf052b9e67345327e42b19cd54e9e/libcxx/include/thread#L296):

```
#ifndef _LIBCPP_CXX03_LANG
    template <class _Fp, class ..._Args,
              class = typename enable_if
              <
                   !is_same<typename __uncvref<_Fp>::type, thread>::value
              >::type
             >
        _LIBCPP_METHOD_TEMPLATE_IMPLICIT_INSTANTIATION_VIS
        explicit thread(_Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args);
#else  // _LIBCPP_CXX03_LANG
    template <class _Fp>
    _LIBCPP_METHOD_TEMPLATE_IMPLICIT_INSTANTIATION_VIS
    explicit thread(_Fp __f);
#endif
```

In C++11 and higher, the constructor adheres to the C++11 standard. Otherwise, it accepts only a callable without additional arguments. I managed to [reproduce your error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1WY2HPnZcThpXUM7) by providing the C++03 standard revision flag. The error even mentions this candidate:

```
prog.cc:16:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::thread'
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");
           ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/wandbox/clang-8.0.0/include/c++/v1/thread:408:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but 2 arguments were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
```